# Computation of fault interpretation and polyline intersections

Tags: ocean

I am planning to make functionality that can test if a borehole is crossing a fault. My first idea was to make a workstep component that takes a Borehole and a Fault Interpretation as input and returns the number of intersections. I have already made a workstep that checks if a fault interpretation is intersecting a surface. The core of this function is the following:

```
ICoordinateReferenceSystem inputCRS = PetrelProject.PrimaryProject.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
SpatialUnitsPolicy unitsPolicy = SpatialUnitsPolicy.AllDataInSI;
SpatialContext spatialCtx = new SpatialContext(inputCRS, unitsPolicy);
ISurfaceIntersectionService sis = CoreSystem.GetService<ISurfaceIntersectionService>(arguments.Surface);
foreach (FaultInterpretationPolyline p in arguments.Fault.GetPolylines()) {
    IEnumerable<PolylineSurfaceIntersection> intersections = sis.GetSurfacePolyLineIntersection(arguments.Surface, p.Polyline);
    foreach (PolylineSurfaceIntersection intersection in intersections) {
        arguments.NumberOfIntersections++;
    }
}
```

The above works fine and I was thinking I could make something along the same lines to compute the intersection between a polyline (well trajectory) and a surface generated from the collection of polylines representing the fault interpretation. The key question is, is there a way to get/generate a surface from a collection of polylines? The fault interpretation can be displayed as a surface (triangulated), is this surface accessible from the api? The surface returned from the api must be such that it can be used as an argument to ISurfaceIntersectionService. If this is not possible through the Ocean api, is there a way that the user could prepare the fault interpretation up front making surfaces from the fault interpretations? Or maybe there is a complete different approach to solve the above in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you will have is the creation of the surface. Currently you can only create a RegularHeightFieldSurface which is a surface that has its points located on a lattice. A FaultIntersection will not normally fit this model as it's points are not picked on a regular lattice. Therefore creating surface for the points from a set of fault interpretation picks is the problem.